# Confused by boundedness and convergence of Dirichlet Series (Apostol 11.6 Lemma 2, Theorem 11.8)

Tags: number-theory, convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

Apostol's IANT Section 11.6 is on "The half-plane of convergence of a Dirichlet Series".

In it he proves that if a Dirichlet series

- is **bounded** at $s_0$ then it is also **bounded** at $\sigma>\sigma_0$ (Lemma 2)
- **converges** at $s_0$ then it **converges** at $\sigma>\sigma_0$ (Theorem 11.8 using Lemma 2).

Images reproduced below to aid readers. Here we follow the traditional notation $s=\sigma+it$.

---

**Question:** My confusion is as follows.

- Lemma 2 is only about boundedness, not convergence.
- However Apostol extends Lemma 2 to show that the series $\left|\sum_{a<n\leq b}f(n)s^{-s} \right| \leq Ka^{\sigma_0-\sigma}$ converges, because the RHS tends to $0$ as $a\rightarrow\infty$. Here $K$ is independent of $a$.

My conclusion is then that if a series is bounded at $s_0$ then it is bounded at any $s$ with $\sigma>\sigma_0$ (lemma 2), and by Apostol's extended argument, it also converges at any $s$ with $\sigma>\sigma_0$. **This seems wrong.  What have I misunderstood?**

To add to my confusion, $\sigma-\sigma_0$ can be as small as we want, which suggests a series converges if it is bounded even at $\sigma$.

---

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, the first part of your argument is correct.  The proof of Theorem $11.8$ uses only boundedness, not convergence.  The second part, that boundedness at a point implies convergence at that point is incorrect.

Let $$F(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)n^{-s},$$  where $f(n)$ is defined, rather informally, as follows.  We consider the partial sums when $s=1$.

$f(1) = 1$.  So long as the partial sum so far is less than $2$, we define $f(n)=1$.  So $f(2)=f(3)=f(4)=1$.  Now $1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14>2$, and we define $f(n)=-1$ until the partial sum is $<-2$, when we reverse course again, defining $f(n)=1$ again, until we exceed $2$, and so on.

Clearly, the partial sums are bounded, but the series does not converge.  I think the point you are missing is that when $\sigma=\sigma_0$, we would have a division by $0$ in the bound in the lemma, so that the proof breaks down.

Comment: Thanks @saulspatz for your useful comments. I didn't spot the division by zero, which as you say causes the proof to break down. For clarity, is the following correct?- If a series is bounded at $s_0$ then it is bounded at any $s$ with $\sigma>\sigma_0$ (lemma 2), and by Apostol's extended argument, it also converges at any $s$ with $\sigma>\sigma_0$. I find this a surprising conclusion.

Comment: As a second comment, Theorem 11.8 starts with the assumption that a series converges at $s_0$ to conclude by lemma 2 (which is about boundedness) that is also converges to the right of that point $\sigma>\sigma_0$. Why is this a valid argument? Is it because convergence is subset of boundedness?

Comment: As to your first comment, I agree.  As to the second, a convergent series is bound.